# Windows SSO-Login only working once in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, single-sign-on

We're about to migrate our users from Internet Explorer 8 to version 11. While testing the IIS-Windows-Authentication, I noticed that it does work, but it will only work once.

I can press the automatic login button on my application, which should take the windows credentials and authenticate the user. This works fine in IE8, but in IE11 this will work exactly once - ever. Restarting or deleting cache does not help, it will always prompt for login details.

As I mentioned, the web server is an IIS running on Windows Server 2008 R2. Since I'm not so familiar with IIS, I have no idea if this might be a client (Windows 7 with IE11) or server problem. Anyone got an idea where to start looking or what might be causing problems?